# What is a "Naturstimme?"

Tags: voice, terminology

At a recent audition, the conductor of the choral ensemble said that my voice had a *Naturstimme*-like quality. (The conductor is, of course, German.) However, I can't seem to find a good definition of what exactly constitutes a *Naturstimme*?

Is this a good thing, or is it a sign that my voice needs a lot of extra work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this context, "Naturstimme" means "untrained voice". It's neither a compliment nor a detraction.

I believe that he is pointing out that you do not sound like a classically-trained singer who learns to sing in the operatic manner. Whether he would prefer a "Naturstimme" or a "Kunstgesangstimme" (an "art-song-trained" voice) for his choir is another matter.

There is a vocal technique forum discussion on this very subject that I read in looking for this answer. The entire forum and the discussion are in German.

[Was heißt "Naturstimme"?](http://www.musiker-board.de/gesangspraxis-voc/383248-heisst-naturstimme.html)